# The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()' I cant seem to see where the error is

Tags: flutter, void

> I'm exploring the language flutter and I encountered this error. Here is the answerQuestion function

```
void _answerQuestion(int score) {
  totalScore += score;
  if (_questionIndex < _questions.length) {
    print("We have more qiestions");
  }
  setState(() {
    _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
  });

  print(_questionIndex);
}
```

> The error

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My first App'),
      ),
      body: _questionIndex < _questions.length
          ? Quiz(
              answerQuestion: _answerQuestion, //the error
              questions: _questions,
              questionIndex: _questionIndex,
            )
```

> Here is the quiz.dart code as requested. There is an error too at () => answerQuestion(answer['score']).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Answer.dart';
import './question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final VoidCallback answerQuestion;
  final int questionIndex;

  Quiz(
      {required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questions,
      required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(
              () => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'] as String);//the error
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add the code snippet for Quiz widget

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't know the interface of the `Quiz` class but seems like the `answerQuestion` argument is expecting a function of type `void ()`, rather than `void (int)` like `_answerQuestion`.

If you were to provide a complete code sample, including the `Quiz` class, identifying the issue would be much easier.

EDIT:
Try changing the type of `answerQuestion` to `void Function(int)`.

Comment: I just added the Quiz class

Comment: Well, now it's clear - `Quiz` expects to receive a `Void Callback` for `answerQuestion`, but is given a function which accepts an int. Try changing the type of `answerQuestion` accordingly to `void Function(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

small change done your work

```
Function()? questions; --> Function(int)? questions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the initialization of the function from a `VoidCallBack` to `Function` on the `Quiz` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how i solve this by reading a lot of stack overflow,
basically change  `final void Function() answerQuestions;` to `final Function(int) answerQuestions;` and also change this `answerQuestions(answer["score"] as int)`

```
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';

import './questions.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quizz extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(int) answerQuestions;
  
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions; 
  final int questionesIndex;
  
  Quizz({required this.questions, required this.questionesIndex, required this.answerQuestions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionesIndex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionesIndex]["answers"] as List<Map<String, Object>>).map((answer){
          return Answer(() => answerQuestions(answer["score"] as int), answer["text"] as String);
        }).toList()
      ]
  );}
  }
```